# Is it possible to micro-optimize "x = max(a,b); y = min(a,b);"?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, optimization, bit-shift

I had an algorithm that started out like

```
int sumLargest2 ( int * arr, size_t n )
{
    int largest(max(arr[0], arr[1])), secondLargest(min(arr[0],arr[1])); 
    // ...
```

and I realized that the first is probably not optimal because calling `max` and then `min` is repetitious when you consider that the information required to know the minimum is already there once you've found the maximum. So I figured out that I could do

```
   int largest = max(arr[0], arr[1]);
   int secondLargest = arr[0] == largest ? arr[1] : arr[0];
```

to shave off the useless invocation of `min`,  but I'm not sure that actually saves any number of operations. Are there any fancy bit-shifting algorithms that can do the equivalent of

```
int largest(max(arr[0], arr[1])), secondLargest(min(arr[0],arr[1]));
```

?????

Comment: How much of a bottleneck did your benchmarks show these "useless invocations of min" to be?

Comment: First off, why is this optimization necessary at this point?

Comment: It's extraordinarily doubtful you shaved off a useless invocation of min, because your compiler would have inlined it anyway. Do you have any profiling results showing it made a difference? You don't optimize things by guessing at which operations are taking place and guessing further how long each one takes. You just need to measure it (don't forget to compile with optimizations on!). Look at the generated assembly to see if you've even made a difference.

Comment: @Borgleader As far as I know, there is no bottleneck in my program at large

Comment: One thing to note is that I think you're looking at execution time in a human-intuitive way, and unfortunately it's usually not so intuitive. For example, min/max often translate to branchless assembly code just twiddling bits around or, at worst, a conditional move (which doesn't suffer from the possibility of branch misprediction). It might seem faster to just use if/else here and avoid the redundant logic, but you might be trading much more expensive non-redundant logic for very cheap redundant logic which actually makes things worse.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C++, you can use [`std::minmax`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax) to produce a `std::pair` of the minimum and the maximum. This is particularly easy in combination with [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

int largest, secondLargest;
std::tie(secondLargest, largest) = std::minmax(arr[0], arr[1]);
```

GCC, at least, is capable of optimizing the call to minmax into a single comparison, identical to the result of the C code below.

In C, you could write the test out yourself:

```
int largest, secondLargest;
if (arr[0] < arr[1]) {
  largest = arr[1];
  secondLargest = arr[0];
} else {
  largest = arr[0];
  secondLargest = arr[1];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
int largestIndex = arr[1] > arr[0];
int largest = arr[largestIndex];
int secondLargest = arr[1 - largestIndex];
```

The first line relies on an implicit cast of a boolean result to 1 in the case of true and 0 in the case of false.

Comment: Nice! That's a total of 1 comparison, 1 subtraction and 3 assignments. Better than what I could come up with.

Comment: No jumps (compiler and processor willing) and no function calls either. I hope you profile each of these potential solutions, I'm curious to know which is actually faster for you.

Answer (score 4):

If your intention is to reduce the function call to find min mad max you can try `std::minmax_element`. This is available since C++11.

```
auto result = std::minmax_element(arr, arr+n);
std::cout<< "min:"<< *result.first<<"\n";
std::cout<< "max :" <<*result.second << "\n";
```

Comment: `std::minmax_element` returns a pair of iterators, not values. You need to dereference them if you want to output the results.

Comment: It's true that `std::minmax` returns a pair of `const T&` (I don't know why you just said "references to iterators"). The code in your answer uses `std::minmax_element` which is a completely different function.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Oh confused, and corrected the answer. Thanks to identify it!!

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to assume that you'd rather solve the larger problem... That is, getting the sum of the largest two numbers in an array.

What you are trying to do is a [`std::partial_sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort).
Let's implement it.

```
int sumLargest2(int * arr, size_t n) {
    int * first  = arr;
    int * middle = arr + 2;
    int * last   = arr + n;

    std::partial_sort(first, middle, last, std::greater<int>());

    return arr[0] + arr[1];
}
```

And if you're unable to modify `arr`, then I'd recommend looking into [`std::partial_sort_copy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort_copy).

Answer (score 4):

```
x = max(a, b);
y = a + b - x;
```

It won't necessarily be faster, but it will be different.

Also beware of overflows.

Comment: `y = a ^ b ^ x` avoids overflows.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to find the bigger of two values go:

```
if(a > b)
{
    largest = a;
    second = b;
}
else
{
     largest = b;
     second = a;
}
```

No function calls, one comparison, two assignments.

Answer (score 2):

How about a time-space trade-off?

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
    std::pair<T, T>
        minmax(T const& a, T const& b)
        { return b < a ? std::make_pair(b, a) : std::make_pair(a, b); }

//main
std::pair<int, int> values = minmax(a[0], a[1]);
int largest       = values.second;
int secondLargest = values.first;
```

Comment: There already exists a [`std::minmax`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax) that looks pretty similar to what you've written.

Comment: Yes it is. OP has tagged C++, not C++11.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming C++...

**Short answer**, use std::minmax and compile with the right optimizations and the right instruction set parameters.

**Long ugly answer**, The compiler cannot make all the assumptions necessary to make it really, really fast. You can. In this case, you can change the algorithm to process all data first and you can force alignment on the data. Doing all this, you can use intrinsics to make it faster.

Although I haven't tested it in this particular case, I've seen enormous performance improvements using these guidelines.

Since you're not passing 2 integers to the function, I'm assuming your using an array and want to iterate it somehow. You now have a choice to make: make 2 arrays and use min/max or use 1 array with both `a` and `b`. This decision alone can already influence the performance.

If you have 2 arrays, these can be allocated on 32-byte boundaries with aligned malloc's and then processed using intrinsics. If you are going for real, raw performance - this is the way to go.

F.ex, let's assume you have AVX2. (NOTE: I'm not sure if you do and you SHOULD check this using CPU id's!). Go to the cheat sheet here: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/ and pick your poison.

The intrinsics you're looking for are in this case probably:

- _mm256_min_epi32
- _mm256_max_epi32
- _mm256_stream_load_si256

If you have to do this for the entire array, you probably want to keep all the stuff in a single __mm256 register before merging the individual items. E.g.: do a min/max per 256-bit vector, and when the loop is done, extract the 32-bit items and do a min/max on that.

**Long nicer answer**: So ... as for the compiler. Compilers do attempt to optimize these kinds of things, but run into problems.

If you have 2 different arrays that you process, the compiler has to know that they are different in order to be able to optimize it. This is the reason why stuff like [restrict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bcxafdh.aspx) exists, which tells the compiler exactly this little thing you probably already knew while writing the code.

Also, the compiler doesn't know your memory is aligned, so it has to check this and branch... for each call. We don't want this; which means we want it to inline its stuff. So, add `inline`, put it in a header file and that's that. You can also use `aligned` to give him a hint.

Your compiler also didn't get the hint that the `int*` won't change over time. If it cannot change, it's a good idea to tell him that using the `const` keyword.

A compiler uses an instruction set to do the compilation. Normally, they already use SSE, but AVX2 can help a lot (as I've shown with the intrinsics above). If you *can* compile it with those flags, make sure to use them - they help a lot.

Run in release mode, compile with optimizations on 'fast' and see what happens under the hood. If you do all this, you should see `vpmax...` instructions appearing in the inner loops, which means that the compiler uses the intrinsics just fine.

I don't know what else you want to do in the loop... if you use all these instructions you should hit the memory speed on big arrays.